# Explain step by step

Tags: matrices

Show that $P^{-1}AP=B$ where $P=(I-(A+B))$.Given that $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$. .Please explain this step by step since I am unable to solve this problem .I only solve $A(I-(A+B))=A-A^2-AB=-AB$ since $A^2=A$.

Comment: Please, first, explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: Write $AP = PB$ and see what that gives you. It's just basic algebra.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: thanks. You solve my problem

Comment: Note that $P$ might not be invertible, so, to be precise, you can only show that $P^{-1}AP=B$ if $P$ is invertible (whereas $AP=PB$ is independent of that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ A(I-(A+B)) = A - A^2 - AB = -AB $$
Also we have
$$ (I-(A+B))B = B - AB - B^2 = -AB $$
So we can conclude the the LHS on both equations are equal, i.e.
$$ A(I-(A+B)) = (I-(A+B))B  $$
which is $AP = PB,$ and if $P$ is invertible, we have $P^{-1} AP = P^{-1}PB = B.$

Comment: Please point out which step is confusing you?

Comment: I got it from Karolis comment but thank you for complete solution

Answer (score 1):

$$PB=(I-(A+B))B=B-AB-B^2=-AB\\AP=A(I-(A+B))=A-A^2-AB=-AB$$